# PHPSpreadsheet loses styles of existing Charts during excel file editing

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I use PHPSpreadsheet to edit existed Excel file and add there some images. But sometimes it losses the styles of existed charts in an excel. It resets a background color or a scale of the chart. Some charts are left without changes.

Could someone say why PHPSpreadsheet resets styles/scale of existed charts and how to suppress that side-effect?

```
<?php

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$inputExcelPath = __DIR__.'/assets/badExcel/an_excel_file.xlsx';
$outputExcelFile = __DIR__.'/excelOutput/'.time().'_'.'/an_excel_file.xlsx';

//load excel
$excelFIleInfo = new SplFileInfo($inputExcelPath);
$excelReader = IOFactory::createReaderForFile($excelFIleInfo->getRealPath());
$excelReader->setIncludeCharts(true);
$excel = $excelReader->load($excelFIleInfo->getRealPath());
//end loading

$excel->setActiveSheetIndex((int)0);

//add image
$drawing = new Drawing();
$drawing->setPath(__DIR__.'/assets/image.jpg');
$drawing->setCoordinates('Q5');
$drawing->setHeight(80);
$drawing->setWidth(140);
$drawing->setWorksheet($excel->getActiveSheet());
//end add image

//save edited excel to a new file
$writer = new Xlsx($excel);
$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
$writer->setIncludeCharts(true);
$writer->save($outputExcelFile);
```

[Link to an example of the excel file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z8CouKA1YKDOvFlxidk8sLf3EheCJBbu/view?usp=sharing)